# WP8 Cordova - cordova-sqlite-legacy plugin not working

Tags: sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I am using the `cordova-sqlite-legacy` plugin on my windows phone 8 cordova project but I cannot get it to work. I am running `cordova 3.5.0`.

I have added the plugin through command line, and all the files have been added to my project successfully, but I can't seem to get the app to recognize the plugin.

This is what is in my cordova_plugins.js file referencing the plugin

```
{
    "file": "plugins/cordova-sqlite-legacy/www/SQLitePlugin.js",
    "id": "cordova-sqlite-legacy.SQLitePlugin",
    "clobbers": [
        "SQLitePlugin"
    ]
}

METADATA
"cordova-sqlite-legacy": "1.3.1"
```

My config.xml reference

```
<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
    <param name="wp-package" value="SQLitePlugin" />
</feature>
```

In my app I am trying to run the database code

```
SQLitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'cordova_demo.db', location: 'default' });
```

However, I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SQLitePlugin is not defined
```

I have tried changing the code to...

```
window.SQLitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'cordova_demo.db', location: 'default' });
```

...but still no luck.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I have followed the instructions from the [plugin website](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-legacy) but I am getting nowhere

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the command

```
SQLitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'cordova_demo.db', location: 'default' });
```

to

```
sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'cordova_demo.db', location: 2 });
```

It was referenced as uppercase letters in the cordova_plugins file but it needs to be lowercase in order for it to work. Also the location needed to be a number too.

Hope this helps someone out.